# Connection to access point "Network subsystem is down"

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to connect to an access point (my lap top is connected to the device) using the xamarin platform, but when trying it generates the following error "Network subsystem is down".

```
try
{

IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 502);
mSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
mSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = 256;
mSocket.SendBufferSize = 256;

mSocket.Connect(server);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     DisplayAlert("Aviso.", "Ocurrió un error al intentar obtener los datos, intentelo más tarde.", "Aceptar");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Agrego una captura de pantalla donde puedo acceder al dispositivo Access Point.

[image]

Comment: I test the code you provided. There is no error on my PC. Have you check your IP address? How do you get it? Using `ipconfig` for cmd?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the IP address of the Access Point, such address is the one I am adding in my code and I access the Access Point administration panel through its IP.

Comment: I am using xamarin, can some configuration be missing?

Comment: Your code works properly on my side. I'm not sure this is caused by the ip. But I consumed Forms 4.3.0.908675 to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I located the port number of the Access Point and in the c # code it was different

Comment: Does you problem resolved with the port number?

Comment: @Jack Hua - MSFT yes i matched the device port number with the code, the device had a 2280 port i changed it to 502

Comment: You can share your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem:).